# Which is the gerund and participle here?

Tags: verbs, gerunds, participles

> Having forgotten him, he went away.

Is **'having'** gerund or participle?

Is **'forgotten'** gerund or participle?

And why?

Comment: "Forgotten" is a participle.  The *-en* forms are never gerunds.  This "having" is also a participle.  Gerunds (and the phrases they form) do the kinds of job that nouns typically do.  Here, "having forgotten him" is a supplemental modifier -- the kind of job that an adverb typically does.

Comment: What is a compound gerund?

Comment: Are having and forgotten one participle or each of them individual participles?

Comment: "Having" is the kind of verb form that's called a present participle.  "Forgotten" is the kind of verb form that's called a past participle.  "Him" is the singular objective third-person masculine pronoun.  "Having forgotten him" is a complete participial phrase.  That's three individual words (two of which happen to be participles) that form one coherent phrase.

Comment: Also, using two masculine pronouns (*him* and *he*) for two different people is not a good idea, especially if the context gives no clues to tell which does what.

Comment: @Gary Botnovcan - It is a parenthetical gerund phrase.  'Having' is a gerund of the auxiliary verb 'had'.

Comment: @aml, Gerund phrases must be the subject of a verb. See these examples: http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/gerundphrase.htm ... unless you can find a reference to the contrary...

Answer (score 1):

> Is **'having'** gerund or participle?

For English *-ing* forms, the traditional distinction is that the term *gerund* is used for their noun-like uses (referring to the action), whereas the term *present participle* is used for their adjective-like uses (describing the actor); in your case, *having* is an example of the latter, so it is a present pariciple. (A similar example with a true adjective would be "*Angry* at having been forgotten, he […]").

That said, modern grammars of English do not always bother with this distinction, referring to *-ing* forms as "*-ing* forms" or *gerund-participles* or whatnot so as to avoid having to classify each usage in this way.

> Is **'forgotten'** gerund or participle?

It is a past participle. As applied to English, the term *gerund* only ever refers to *-ing* forms (which double as present participles), never to the *-ed/-en* forms.

Answer (score 0):

[Gerund phrases](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/gerundphrase.htm) and Participial phrases sometimes look alike, but a participial phrase stands on its own, whereas a gerund phrase must be the subject or object of a verb.

> **Walking down the street**, he noticed that there was a lot of litter on the pavement. - *participial phrase*
>
> **Walking down the street** is not as safe as it used to be - *gerund phrase, subject of **is***
>
> One of my favourite activities is **walking down the street** - *gerund phrase, object of **is***

In your sentence, **having forgotten him** is neither the subject nor the object of a verb, so it is a participial phrase. **having** is an active/present participle (the bit that makes it a participial phrase), and **forgotten** is a past participle.

Comment: "Is" does not take an object.